# GFDL and CC BY-SA compatibility and Use

Tags: license-compatibility, cc-by-sa, gfdl

For Free/Opensource documentation, There are two license widely used.

1. [GNU Free Documentation License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl-1.3.txt)
2. [Creative Commons BY-Share Alike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)

Both say re-distribution must be under same license as GFDL is copyleft and CC-BY-SA is with share-alike attribution.

So, I want to know whether they are compatible with each other or not? Further which should be used when?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 legal code](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) (version 4.0 has similar wording):

> You may Distribute or Publicly Perform an Adaptation only under the terms of:...(iv) a Creative Commons Compatible License.
>
> "Creative Commons Compatible License" means a license that is listed at https://creativecommons.org/compatiblelicenses that has been approved by Creative Commons as being essentially equivalent to this License

From the above link:

> Currently, no non-CC licenses have been designated as compatible with BY-SA 3.0
>
> Currently, the Free Art license 1.3 is the only “BY-SA–Compatible License” for version 4.0.

So no, you cannot incorporate content from a CC-BY-SA work into a GFDL work.

Going the other direction is even more restrictive.  From [section 4 of the GFDL 1.3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl-1.3.txt):

> You may copy and distribute a Modified Version of the Document under
> the conditions of sections 2 and 3 above, provided that you release
> the Modified Version under precisely this License

It's quite explicit that the only permissible license for a derivative work of a GFDL document is the GFDL.  Section 11 (relicensing) doesn't change anything: it's essentially the "Wikipedia clause", included to permit the Wikimedia Foundation to change from the GFDL to CC-BY-SA.

In general, if you are interested in creating genuinely open content, [the GFDL should not be used](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BD-propagande_colour_en.jpg).  The mechanics of complying with it are extremely unwieldy: in particular, the requirement to include a copy of the 23KB of license text make it impractical for anything but electronic content or book-sized printed works.